# React-native maps await promise.all

Tags: javascript, react-native

native, i had tried using await and .then but when i run the code it will direct skip into dispatch(successGetPostList)

```js
 userRef = firestore.collection('user')
            const postList = []
            await Promise.all(user.userFollowing.map(async (val) => {
                postRef = firestore.collection('post').where('postOwner', '==', firestore.collection('user').doc(val))
                await postRef.onSnapshot(async (collection) => {
                   await Promise.all(collection._docs.map(async (doc) => {
                           let post =doc.data()
                         await post.postOwner.get().then((user)=>{
                             let owner={
                                 ...user.data()
                             }
                             post ={
                                 ...post,
                                 postId:doc.id,
                                 owner:owner
                             }
                             postList.push(post)
                            })
                        }))
                    })
                }))
                dispatch(_successGetPostList(postList))
```

Comment: You never wait for `postRef.onSnapshot`. Assuming that it happens only once, use a promise here and do not pass a callback.

Comment: even though i added promise for postRef.onSnapshot the problem still same, sorry i don't get what you mean do not pass a callback

Comment: You added a `Promise.all` now, but does the `postRef.onSnapshot(…)` call actually return anything useful?

Comment: So j just need to add await for it?

Comment: This code is a mess, I would suggest to divide the code into separate functions, simplify it and maybe if not us, you will be able to debug it.

Comment: @karl No, you need to check what it returns. Read the documentation. How can one wait for it to finish?